# Weird symbols / encoding showing up in output Python txt files

Tags: python, parsing, encoding

I'm having a frustrating issue outputting to text files from Python. Actually, the files appear perfectly normal when opened up in a text editor, but I am uploading these files into QDA miner, a data analysis suite and once they are uploaded into QDA miner, this is what the text looks like:

```
.Â â€¨â€¨"This problem really needs to be focused in a way that is particular to its cultural dynamics and tending in the industry,"
```

As you can see, many of these weird (Â â€¨â€¨) symbols show up throughout the texts. The text that my python script parses initially is a RTF file that I convert to plain text using OSX's built in text editor.

Is there an easy way to remove these symbols? I am parsing over singular 100+mb text files and separating them into thousands of separate articles, I have to have a way to batch convert them otherwise it will be near impossible. I should also mention that the origin of these text files is copied from webpages.

Here is some relevant code from the script I wrote:

```
test1 = filedialog.askopenfile()
newFolder = ((str(test1)[25:])[:-32])
folderCreate(newFolder)
masterFileName = newFolder+"/"+"MASTER_FILE"
masterOutput = open(masterFileName,"w")
edit = test1.readlines()
for i,line in enumerate(edit):
    for j in line.split():
        if j in ["Author","Author:"]:
            try:
                outputFileName = "-".join(edit[i-2].lower().title().split())+".txt"
                output = open(newFolder+"/"+outputFileName,"w") # create file with article name # backslashed changed to front slash windows
                print("File created - ","-".join(edit[i-2].lower().title().split()))
                counter2 = counter2+1
            except:
                print("Filename error.")
                counter = counter+1
                pass


            #Count number of words in each article
            wordCount = 0
            for word in edit[i+1].split():
                wordCount+=1
            fileList.append((outputFileName,str(wordCount)))

            #Now write to file
            output.write(edit[i-2])
            output.write("\n")
            author = line
            output.write(author) # write article author
            output.write("\n")
            output.write("\n")
            content = edit[i+1]
            output.write(content) # write article content
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to figure out the target's encoding and encode the files in it.

Comment: The target, as in QDA miner? I have successfully removed the symbols by a series of conversions within OpenOffice, but there's now way I can manually convert all the files that way. Is there a way to do this in batch, or within Python, to output to plain-text?

Comment: There is but I'll have to see some code. I'm just blind here :)

Comment: Ok, I've posted the parts of my script that I would consider most relevant.

Comment: That's a lot of code, when writing output, try to do in the code the same you did to remove it in OpenOffice. Which should be erasing the first bytes of the string.

Comment: In openOffice all I did was save the output files of the Python Script as Word95 files then back to RTF to be input into QDA. If I simply output the files from python as RTF files the weird characters remain. Something in the process of saving these as Word95 files then back to RTF removes that. Unfortunately it won't be possible to do that for 1000's of files.

Comment: I know there are ways to script OpenOffice with python, but I don't want to get into that.

Comment: I have yet to find a way to programatically output the text without the symbols or formatting attached/

Comment: Could you post sample files (rtf and txt)?